# How many permutations of length $n$ differ from a particular permutation of length $n$ in at most $k$ positions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $P$ be a permutation on the set $\mathbb{N}_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x < n\}$, such that $n > 2$. How many permutations on $\mathbb{N}_n$ exist that differ from $P$ in $k$ positions? I know that for $k = 0$, there's only $1$ ($P$ itself), and for $k = 1$, there are $0$, as this is impossible, but for $k > 1$, I don't know how to compute this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the permutation $P$, you can construct a permutation from $P$, by first choosing which $k$ places you need altered, and this can be done in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. Once the $k$ elements are selected you need to arrange these $k$ elements such that none of the element is put back in its original position - this problem is called the [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) problem. It is given by $$D(k)=k! \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
Try to show this principle of exclusion and inclusion. So your required answer is $\binom nkD(k)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For a specific $k$ you have to choose which $k$ of the $n$ positions disagree, then make a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of those positions.